# Generate a pandas dataframe from list of list

Tags: python, list, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I am wondering how to generate a pd DataFrame from a list of list which in this form:

Input:

```
A=[['a','b','c'],['c','d','e'],['f','g','h']]
```

Output:(in a dataframe)

```
No content   
0 'a'
0 'b'
0 'c'
1 'c'
1 'd'
1 'e'
2 'f'
2 'g'
2 'h'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd
A1 = pd.DataFrame(A).stack().reset_index().drop('level_1', 1).rename(columns = {'level_0': "No", 0: "content"})

A1
#  No  content
#0  0        a
#1  0        b
#2  0        c
#3  1        c
#4  1        d
#5  1        e
#6  2        f
#7  2        g
#8  2        h
```

Or you can flatten your list firstly and then construct data frame from it:

```
dicA = {"No":[], "content":[]}
for i, s in enumerate(A):
    for e in s:
        dicA['No'].append(i)
        dicA['content'].append(e)

import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(dicA)

#  No  content
#0  0        a
#1  0        b
#2  0        c
#3  1        c
#4  1        d
#5  1        e
#6  2        f
#7  2        g
#8  2        h
```

Answer (score 2):

You can melt the transpose of the dataframe to produce your desired result.

```
import pandas as pd

>>> pd.melt(pd.DataFrame(A).T, var_name='No.', value_name='content')
   No. content
0    0       a
1    0       b
2    0       c
3    1       c
4    1       d
5    1       e
6    2       f
7    2       g
8    2       h
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this use zip() on your list:

```
df = pd.melt(pd.DataFrame(zip(*A))).rename(columns= {'variable':'no','value':'content' })


    no content
0   0       a
1   0       b
2   0       c
3   1       c
4   1       d
5   1       e
6   2       f
7   2       g
8   2       h
```